# How to generate namespace prefixed xml elements using SimpleXMLElement in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to generate a RSS feed using PHP `SimpleXMLElement`, the problem is that i need to prefix elements and can't find a way to do this using the `SimpleXMLElement` class.

I've tried using `$item->addChild('prefix:element', 'value')` but in the result xml it strips the prefix, *any idea why this happens ?*.

I wonder if there is a way to solve this using the `SimpleXMLElement` or any other *cleaner* way than just *echoing* the XML.

For clarification, this is my PHP code:

```
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"/>');
    $channel = $xml->addChild('channel');
    $channel->addChild('title', 'Text');
    $channel->addChild('link', 'http://example.com');
    $channel->addChild('description', 'An example item from the feed.');

    foreach($this->products as $product) {
        $item = $channel->addChild('item');

        foreach($product as $key => $value)
            $item->addChild($key, $value);
    }

    return $xml->asXML();
```

And this is the example XML i'm trying to generate:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
<channel>
    <title>Test Store</title>
    <link>http://www.example.com</link>
    <description>An example item from the feed</description>

    <item>
        <g:id>DB_1</g:id>
        <g:title>Dog Bowl In Blue</g:title>
        <g:description>Solid plastic Dog Bowl in marine blue color</g:description>
        ...
    </item>
...
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the namespace uri of the prefix to add child element with prefix :

```
$item->addChild($key, $value, 'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0');
```

[`eval.in demo`](https://eval.in/480623) :

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"/>');
$channel = $xml->addChild('channel');
$channel->addChild('title', 'Text');
$channel->addChild('link', 'http://example.com');
$channel->addChild('description', 'An example item from the feed.');

$item = $channel->addChild('item');
$item->addChild('g:foo', 'bar', 'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0');

print $xml->asXML();
```